# View pager not smooth scrolly

Tags: android

This is my code my problem is this . in calendar view pager adapter i am 5000 page but offScreenPage limit is 1 and I have 3 pages in on time but view pager is not smoth scroll and has bad performance. when I remove this line from Calendar fragment view pager smooth scroll fine. but I dont know what is the problem.

```
   gregorianCal = new GregorianCalendar(persianCal);
    IslamicCalendar islamicCal = new IslamicCalendar(persianCal);
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////
    for (int i = 0; i < persianCal.getNumberOfDaysInMonth(); i++) {
        DateCalendar dateCalendar = new DateCalendar();

        dateCalendar.nameOFDay = persianCal.getWeekDay();
        //////set month names/////////////
        dateCalendar.shamsiMonthName = persianCal.getMonthName();
        dateCalendar.hejriMonthName = islamicCal.getMonthName();
        dateCalendar.gregorianMonthName = gregorianCal.getMonthName();
        //////set persian calendar/////
        dateCalendar.shamsiDayNumber = persianCal.getDay();
        dateCalendar.shamsiMonthNumber = persianCal.getMonth();
        dateCalendar.shamsiYearNumber = persianCal.getYear();
        //////set islamic calendar/////
        dateCalendar.hejriDayNumber = islamicCal.getDay();
        dateCalendar.hejriMonthNumber = islamicCal.getMonth();
        dateCalendar.hejriYearNumber = islamicCal.getYear();
        //////set gregorian calendar/////
        dateCalendar.gregorianDayNumber = gregorianCal.getDay();
        dateCalendar.gregorianMonthNumber = gregorianCal.getMonth();
        dateCalendar.gregorianYearNumber = gregorianCal.getYear();

        ///////select current day of Month
        if (persianCal.getDay() == currentPersianCal.getDay() && persianCal.getMonth() == currentPersianCal.getMonth() && persianCal.getYear() == currentPersianCal.getYear()) {
            dateCalendar.isCurrentDay = true;
            dateCalendar.isDaySelected = true;
        }
        ///////add days of current month//////
        dateCalendarList.add(dateCalendar);
        if (i < persianCal.getNumberOfDaysInMonth() - 1) {
            persianCal.nextDay();
            gregorianCal.nextDay();
            islamicCal.nextDay();
        }
    }
```

I search a lot of similar subject of viewPager but I not found soultion for it.

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.example.moein.mycalendar.R;
import com.example.moein.mycalendar.myCalendar_adapter.GridAdapter1;
import com.example.moein.mycalendar.myCalendar_library.date.GregorianCalendar;
import com.example.moein.mycalendar.myCalendar_library.date.IslamicCalendar;
import com.example.moein.mycalendar.myCalendar_library.date.PersianCalendar;
import com.example.moein.mycalendar.myCalendar_library.util.Operations;
import com.example.moein.mycalendar.myCalendar_model.DateCalendar;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.TimeZone;

/**
 * Created by Moein on 9/16/2017.
 */



   public class CalendarFragment extends Fragment {

        private int year;
        private int month;
        private int day;

        // newInstance constructor for creating fragment with arguments
        public static CalendarFragment newInstance(int year, int month, int day) {
            CalendarFragment calendarFragment = new CalendarFragment();
            Bundle args = new Bundle();
            args.putInt("year", year);
            args.putInt("month", month);
            args.putInt("day", day);
            calendarFragment.setArguments(args);
            return calendarFragment;
        }

        // Store instance variables based on arguments passed
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            year = getArguments().getInt("year");
            month = getArguments().getInt("month");
            day = getArguments().getInt("day");
        }

        @Nullable
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_calendar, container, false);
            TextView yearAndMonth = view.findViewById(R.id.yearAndMonth);
            GridView gridView = view.findViewById(R.id.gridCalendar);
            /////set timeZone Asia/Tehran and set current calendar///////////////////////////////
            Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
            calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tehran"));
            GregorianCalendar currentGregorianCal = new GregorianCalendar(calendar);
            PersianCalendar currentPersianCal = new PersianCalendar(currentGregorianCal);

            GregorianCalendar gregorianCal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, day);
            PersianCalendar persianCal = new PersianCalendar(gregorianCal);
            /////////add weekDay names to the list of gridAdapter///////
            String[] weekDays = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.weekDays);
            List<DateCalendar> dateCalendarList = new ArrayList<>();
            for (String weekDay : weekDays) {
                DateCalendar dateCalendar = new DateCalendar();
                dateCalendar.nameOFDay = weekDay;
                dateCalendarList.add(dateCalendar);
            }

            //set title of calendar/////////
            yearAndMonth.setText(persianCal.getMonthName() + " " + Operations.toPersianNumber(String.valueOf(persianCal.getYear())));
            ///Back to the beginning of the month
            persianCal.subtractDays(persianCal.getDay() - 1);
            //////add empty days to the beginning of the month
            int lengthOfEmptyDays = 0;
            switch (persianCal.getWeekDay()) {
                case "شنبه":
                    lengthOfEmptyDays = 0;
                    break;
                case "یکشنبه":
                    lengthOfEmptyDays = 1;
                    break;
                case "دوشنبه":
                    lengthOfEmptyDays = 2;
                    break;
                case "سه\u200Cشنبه":
                    lengthOfEmptyDays = 3;
                    break;
                case "چهارشنبه":
                    lengthOfEmptyDays = 4;
                    break;
                case "پنج\u200Cشنبه":
                    lengthOfEmptyDays = 5;
                    break;
                case "جمعه":
                    lengthOfEmptyDays = 6;
                    break;
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < lengthOfEmptyDays; i++) {
                DateCalendar dateCalendar = new DateCalendar();
                dateCalendar.isEmpty = true;
                dateCalendarList.add(dateCalendar);
            }

            gregorianCal = new GregorianCalendar(persianCal);
            IslamicCalendar islamicCal = new IslamicCalendar(persianCal);
            ///////////////////////////////////////////////
            for (int i = 0; i < persianCal.getNumberOfDaysInMonth(); i++) {
                DateCalendar dateCalendar = new DateCalendar();

                dateCalendar.nameOFDay = persianCal.getWeekDay();
                //////set month names/////////////
                dateCalendar.shamsiMonthName = persianCal.getMonthName();
                dateCalendar.hejriMonthName = islamicCal.getMonthName();
                dateCalendar.gregorianMonthName = gregorianCal.getMonthName();
                //////set persian calendar/////
                dateCalendar.shamsiDayNumber = persianCal.getDay();
                dateCalendar.shamsiMonthNumber = persianCal.getMonth();
                dateCalendar.shamsiYearNumber = persianCal.getYear();
                //////set islamic calendar/////
                dateCalendar.hejriDayNumber = islamicCal.getDay();
                dateCalendar.hejriMonthNumber = islamicCal.getMonth();
                dateCalendar.hejriYearNumber = islamicCal.getYear();
                //////set gregorian calendar/////
                dateCalendar.gregorianDayNumber = gregorianCal.getDay();
                dateCalendar.gregorianMonthNumber = gregorianCal.getMonth();
                dateCalendar.gregorianYearNumber = gregorianCal.getYear();

                ///////select current day of Month
                if (persianCal.getDay() == currentPersianCal.getDay() && persianCal.getMonth() == currentPersianCal.getMonth() && persianCal.getYear() == currentPersianCal.getYear()) {
                    dateCalendar.isCurrentDay = true;
                    dateCalendar.isDaySelected = true;
                }
                ///////add days of current month//////
                dateCalendarList.add(dateCalendar);
                if (i < persianCal.getNumberOfDaysInMonth() - 1) {
                    persianCal.nextDay();
                    gregorianCal.nextDay();
                    islamicCal.nextDay();
                }
            }
            gridView.setAdapter(new GridAdapter1(getActivity(), dateCalendarList));
            return view;
        }
    }

public class CalendarViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{

    private GregorianCalendar centerGregorianCalendar;
    private GregorianCalendar nextGregorianCalendar;
    private GregorianCalendar prevGregorianCalendar;
    private final int MAX = 5000;

    public CalendarViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, GregorianCalendar centerGregorianCalendar, GregorianCalendar nextGregorianCalendar, GregorianCalendar prevGregorianCalendar) {
        super(fm);
        this.centerGregorianCalendar = centerGregorianCalendar;
        this.prevGregorianCalendar = prevGregorianCalendar;
        this.nextGregorianCalendar = nextGregorianCalendar;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        position = position % 3;
        if (position == 0) {
            return new CalendarFragment().newInstance(prevGregorianCalendar.getYear(), prevGregorianCalendar.getMonth(), prevGregorianCalendar.getDay());
        } else if (position == 1) {
            return new CalendarFragment().newInstance(centerGregorianCalendar.getYear(), centerGregorianCalendar.getMonth(), centerGregorianCalendar.getDay());
        } else {
            return new CalendarFragment().newInstance(nextGregorianCalendar.getYear(), nextGregorianCalendar.getMonth(), nextGregorianCalendar.getDay());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return MAX;
    }
}


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private int[] CenterPage = {2500};
    private CalendarViewPagerAdapter calendarViewPagerAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        /////set timeZone Asia/Tehran///////////////////////////////
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
        calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Asia/Tehran"));
        final GregorianCalendar gregorianCal = new GregorianCalendar(calendar);
        final GregorianCalendar nextGregorianCal = new GregorianCalendar(calendar);
        final GregorianCalendar prevGregorianCal = new GregorianCalendar(calendar);
        if (gregorianCal.getMonth() == 12) {
            nextGregorianCal.setMonth(1);
            nextGregorianCal.setYear(nextGregorianCal.getYear() + 1);
        } else {
            nextGregorianCal.setMonth(nextGregorianCal.getMonth() + 1);
        }
        if (gregorianCal.getMonth() == 1) {
            prevGregorianCal.setMonth(12);
            prevGregorianCal.setYear(prevGregorianCal.getYear() - 1);
        } else {
            prevGregorianCal.setMonth(prevGregorianCal.getMonth() - 1);
        }

        final ViewPager calendarViewPager = findViewById(R.id.calendar_viewPager);
        calendarViewPagerAdapter = new CalendarViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), gregorianCal, nextGregorianCal, prevGregorianCal);
        calendarViewPager.setAdapter(calendarViewPagerAdapter);
        calendarViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);
        calendarViewPager.setCurrentItem(2500);

        calendarViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                if (position < CenterPage[0]) {
                    switch (position % 3) {
                        case 0:
                            nextGregorianCal.set(prevGregorianCal);
                            if (nextGregorianCal.getMonth() == 1) {
                                nextGregorianCal.setMonth(12);
                                nextGregorianCal.setYear(nextGregorianCal.getYear() - 1);
                            } else {
                                nextGregorianCal.setMonth(nextGregorianCal.getMonth() - 1);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            prevGregorianCal.set(gregorianCal);
                            if (prevGregorianCal.getMonth() == 1) {
                                prevGregorianCal.setMonth(12);
                                prevGregorianCal.setYear(prevGregorianCal.getYear() - 1);
                            } else {
                                prevGregorianCal.setMonth(prevGregorianCal.getMonth() - 1);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            gregorianCal.set(nextGregorianCal);
                            if (gregorianCal.getMonth() == 1) {
                                gregorianCal.setMonth(12);
                                gregorianCal.setYear(gregorianCal.getYear() - 1);
                            } else {
                                gregorianCal.setMonth(gregorianCal.getMonth() - 1);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                } else if (position > CenterPage[0]) {
                    switch (position % 3) {
                        case 0:
                            gregorianCal.set(prevGregorianCal);
                            if (gregorianCal.getMonth() == 12) {
                                gregorianCal.setMonth(1);
                                gregorianCal.setYear(gregorianCal.getYear() + 1);
                            } else {
                                gregorianCal.setMonth(gregorianCal.getMonth() + 1);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            nextGregorianCal.set(gregorianCal);
                            if (nextGregorianCal.getMonth() == 12) {
                                nextGregorianCal.setMonth(1);
                                nextGregorianCal.setYear(nextGregorianCal.getYear() + 1);
                            } else {
                                nextGregorianCal.setMonth(nextGregorianCal.getMonth() + 1);
                            }
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            prevGregorianCal.set(nextGregorianCal);
                            if (prevGregorianCal.getMonth() == 12) {
                                prevGregorianCal.setMonth(1);
                                prevGregorianCal.setYear(prevGregorianCal.getYear() + 1);
                            } else {
                                prevGregorianCal.setMonth(prevGregorianCal.getMonth() + 1);
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                }
                CenterPage[0] = position;
            }

            @Override
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: This is probably not a use case for the view pager. To get a calendar, you may want to use some other widget, i.e. the calendar widget. Otherwise, write a custom view. ViewPager handles a lot of layouting and a lot of additional calculation you probably don't need.

Comment: for custom view for persian calender what is your suggestion please send link. Thank you

Comment: Not really a link. You'll probably need to create a new component, call it PersianCalendar and then write the logic yourself. To do this, google something like "custom view android", or for calendars "calendar custom view" and start from there. Note that this is not an easy task, it requires quite a bit of preparation

Answer (score 0):

i hope you can use this code
my site https://mohammadhosseinaref.ir

```
      public static string PersianDayOfWeek(DayOfWeek dayOfWeek)
{
    switch (dayOfWeek)
    {
        case DayOfWeek.Sunday:
            return "یکشنبه";
        case DayOfWeek.Monday:
            return "دوشنبه";
        case DayOfWeek.Tuesday:
            return "سه شنبه";
        case DayOfWeek.Wednesday:
            return "چهار شنبه";
        case DayOfWeek.Thursday:
            return "پنج شنبه";
        case DayOfWeek.Friday:
            return "جمعه";
        case DayOfWeek.Saturday:
            return "شنبه";
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

  public static Dictionary<int, string> ListOfPersianDayOfMonth(int month, int years)
{
    Dictionary<int, string> dicDays = new Dictionary<int, string>();

    PersianCalendar p = new PersianCalendar();

    var dates = Enumerable.Range(1, p.GetDaysInMonth(years, month))
           .Select(day => ParsePersianToGorgian(years + "/" + month + "/" + day))
           .ToList();

    foreach (var item in dates)
    {
        var day = GeorgianToPersian(item.Value, ShowMode.OnlyDate);
        dicDays.Add(int.Parse(day.Split('/')[2]), DayPersian(item.Value.DayOfWeek) + " " + day);
    }
    return dicDays;
}
```